# Python BeautifulSoup/Requests Loop through pages - doesn't work

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have tried suggestions from the forum to loop through multiple web pages, but it does not work:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    url = f'https://www.xxxx.com/?page={i}' # just a random web page
    result = requests.get(url).text
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')
```

it gives only the first page result so https://www.xxxx.com/?page=1

any suggestion what is wrong here?

Comment: Think loop is not the problem - Are you sure these pages exist? Do you get any error? Maybe your just saving the result of first loop?  Please add some more details - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be very helpful if you provide an Error StackTrace. In general, it is possible to loop scrape multiple pages at once.

Here is a code that worked for me with an arbitrary web page.

```
#!pip install requests
#!pip install beautifulsoup4

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
page = 1
titles = []
for i in range(1,5):
      url = f"https://www.bookdepository.com/bestsellers?page={page}"
      response = requests.get(url)
      html = response.content
      soup = bs(html, "lxml")
      for h3 in soup.find_all("h3", class_="title"):
            titles.append(h3.get_text(strip=True))
      page = page + 1

print(titles)
```

A simple google search revelead the code.
https://data36.com/scrape-multiple-web-pages-beautiful-soup-tutorial/

The range was modified as shown in your example.